# Extract value from embedded dictionaries inside pandas df

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have pandas dataframe:

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $overall | {'all': 26929} | {'all': 2036} |
| QWE | {'$overall': {'all': 6},'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 3},'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 3}} | {'$overall': {'all': 3},'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 2},'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 1} |

Desired output :

| Name | Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $overall |  | 26929 | 2036 |
| QWE | Mar 3, 2021 | 3 | 2 |
| QWE | Mar 18, 2021 | 3 | 1 |

I tried below code and got below output:

```
df = df.apply(lambda s: s.str['all']).fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
```

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $overall | 26929 | 2036 |
| QWE | 0 | 0 |
| QWE | 0 | 0 |

`df.dict()` gives me below:

````
{'A': {'$XYZ': {'all': 26929},   
'QWE': {'$overall': {'all': 6},    
'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 3},    
'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 3}}, }  '
B.': {'$XYZ': {'all': 2036},   
'QWE': {'$overall': {'all': 3},    
'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 2},    
'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 1},   }  
'Name': {'$XYZ': '$overall',   
'QWE': 'QWE',   }}}```
````

Comment: why `Date` should be taken only from `B` column?

Comment: Date is picked from both A and B